How to solve errors (E/W/N) after apt-get apdate?
I am now running 22.04 LTS. After sudo apt update, I got these errors:
Hit:1 https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive jammy InRelease
Hit:2 https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive jammy-updates InRelease         
Hit:3 https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive jammy-backports InRelease       
Get:4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [7,546 B]
Hit:5 https://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive jammy-security InRelease        
Ign:6 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                     
Hit:7 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                       
Hit:8 https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release InRelease      
Err:4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gdm-settings/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I uninstalled brave browser by sudo apt remove brave-browser and sudo apt purge brave-browser. I also deleted the cache and config file of brave browser.

At least one of your problems: The webupd8 ppa hasn't been updated in years and doesn't have a jammy release. You should figure out what software you have installed from there if any and install the versions from the ubuntu repos or just remove them if there are no current versions. Then remove the ppa from your sources.

A quick look at https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager  (from your provided details!) shows its no longer maintained... PPAs are 3rd party software sources, so all security checks are your responsibility, and matter if you care about security.
